# filemaker api pass array object

Tags: arrays, api, filemaker

I have in Filemaker pro 18, a text reptition field defined like below:

[image]

I want to pass an array of value into this field.

I tried doing below in the raw data but it's saying parameter value is invalid

```
{
    "fieldData": {        
        "Temp_Foodbank_Employement_Type": ["test","test2"]
    }
}
```

Comment: The [Data API Guide](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/18/en/dataapi/) makes no mention of repeating fields (except in the context of uploading container data). I see no reason to assume that an array would work. Have you tried addressing a specific repetition individually - e.g.`{"Temp_Foodbank_Employement_Type[2]": "test2"}`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k {"Temp_Foodbank_Employement_Type[2]": "test2"} gives a field is missing error. looks like the api doesn't recognize Temp_Foodbank_Employement_Type[2]

Comment: Well, it was just a shot in the dark. If you cannot find it through experimentation, ask Claris tech support. It's quite possible it's not supported at all.

Comment: I do not think it is supported, can't find any mentioning of them in manual. May be try to set through the script with parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while, but the correct syntax is actually just use the regular bracket, and the array starts at 1 instead of 0. So a typical data field would be:

```
{
    "fieldData": {
        "family_member(1)":"John",
        "family_member(2)":"Steve"
    }
}
```